# SQL Server Table linked to SharePoint list

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010

All,

I would like to create table on SQL Server which is linked with SharePoint list.
The same as you can do that in Access by: External Data -> More -> Sharepoint List (Import or Link to Sharepoint List). 
Every change made on List is also save on table.

I understood that I can share my SQL table on SharePoint. But I want to do this in the other way. I got list already, I would like to link it with SQL table.

Thank you,
TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible.. but... not recommended and too complicated!!
if you want data from a SharePoint list, you need to solve this using web services (REST)
[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx)